# Why does subtracting the value of etext from edata not give me the correct size for my text segment

Tags: c, linux, elf

I have a C source code file like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char etext, edata, end;

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {

    printf("TEXT END: %p\n", &etext);
    printf("DATA END: %p\n", &edata);
    printf("PROG BRK: %p\n", &end);

    register long volatile sp asm("rsp");
    printf("STCK PTR: %p\n", sp);

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives me this output -

```
TEXT END: 0x5565d48661d5
DATA END: 0x5565d4869018
PROG BRK: 0x5565d4869020
STCK PTR: 0x7fff8f6f34d0
```

To my understanding, the text, data, and bss segments are laid out sequentially in memory with no space between them. But `(&edata - &etext)` is `0x2e43` while `size -x a.out` says the size of the data section is `0x250`. Why does this happen?

I am using gcc 12.2.0 on linux x86_64 5.19.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To my understanding, the text, data, and bss segments are laid out sequentially in memory with no space between them.

That used to be true a long time ago. Nowadays it usually isn't the case, for several different reasons.

Also, back when it *was* true, `edata - etext` would give you the size of the *data* segment, not the text segment.

To get a look at the actual layout of the address space on a current-generation Linux-based Unix, you can read `/proc/self/maps`, and/or you can use [`dl_iterate_phdr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html).  Unfortunately, both of these APIs are Linux-specific. Below is a demo program that takes the latter approach (note: some of this code assumes a 64-bit address space).

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <elf.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_flags(const ElfW(Phdr) *p) {
    putchar((p->p_flags & PF_R) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((p->p_flags & PF_W) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((p->p_flags & PF_X) ? 'x' : '-');

    ElfW(Word) other_flags = p->p_flags & ~(PF_R | PF_W | PF_X);
    if (other_flags) {
        printf("/%08x", other_flags);
    }
}

static int callback(struct dl_phdr_info *dlpi, size_t size, void *data) {
    if (dlpi->dlpi_name[0] == '\0') {
        puts("Main executable:");
    } else {
        printf("%s:\n", dlpi->dlpi_name);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dlpi->dlpi_phnum; i++) {
        if (dlpi->dlpi_phdr[i].p_type != PT_LOAD) {
            continue;
        }
        uint64_t start =
            (uint64_t)(dlpi->dlpi_addr + dlpi->dlpi_phdr[i].p_vaddr);
        uint64_t end = start + dlpi->dlpi_phdr[i].p_memsz;
        printf("  [%016lx, %016lx) ", start, end);
        print_flags(&dlpi->dlpi_phdr[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    dl_iterate_phdr(callback, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output will be something like this:

```
$ ./a.out
Main executable:
  [000056371bce2000, 000056371bce2730) r--
  [000056371bce3000, 000056371bce3315) r-x
  [000056371bce4000, 000056371bce4168) r--
  [000056371bce5da0, 000056371bce6020) rw-
linux-vdso.so.1:
  [00007ffe1ff9c000, 00007ffe1ff9cdcd) r-x
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
  [00007f1c05caf000, 00007f1c05cd6fe0) r--
  [00007f1c05cd7000, 00007f1c05e6b4c1) r-x
  [00007f1c05e6c000, 00007f1c05ec38cc) r--
  [00007f1c05ec48f0, 00007f1c05ed6e50) rw-
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:
  [00007f1c05f0c000, 00007f1c05f0db50) r--
  [00007f1c05f0e000, 00007f1c05f37335) r-x
  [00007f1c05f38000, 00007f1c05f42ee4) r--
  [00007f1c05f44620, 00007f1c05f472d8) rw-
```

As you can see, for each module, the "segments" printed by this program do not correspond to the traditional 3-way division into text, data, and bss.  *Approximately speaking*, the "r-x" segment holds the text and the "rw-" segment holds the *combination* of data and bss.  The "r--" segments hav no traditional analogue. It may be useful to compare this program's output with the output of `readelf --program-headers` on the executable and each of its shared libraries.

Comment: So what *is* the layout of program sections in memory in the current day? If the old model of text -> data -> bss -> heap -> ... -> stack -> kernel no longer holds true then why do so many sources online and in textbooks still describe process layouts using it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any good documentation for the way it is now. The references you're talking about simply haven't been updated — textbook material changes on a 10- to 20-year cycle.

Answer (score 2):

This program layout test used to work for unix programs in the old days. It still does to some extend on selected systems, such as linux, but the `etext`, `edata` and `end` should be declared as arrays as they are addresses, not variables:

```
extern char etext[], edata[], end[];
```

Here is a modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char etext[], edata[], end[];

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

    // Note that main is usually not the first item in the text segment
    printf("main    : %p\n", (void *)main);
    printf("TEXT END: %p\n", (void *)etext);
    printf("DATA END: %p\n", (void *)edata);
    printf("PROG BRK: %p\n", (void *)end);

    void *sp = &argc;
    printf("STCK PTR: %p\n", sp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output on my linux system:

```
main    : 0x4004b0
TEXT END: 0x40068d
DATA END: 0x600a40
PROG BRK: 0x600a48
STCK PTR: 0x7ffc52b616bc
```

As you can see, the text and data segments are not contiguous on this system, so the size of the text segment. `edata - etext` used to evaluate to the size of the **data** segment, but this no longer works.

Also note that successive runs of the program may output different addresses on modern systems because of address space randomization, a technique that makes it more difficult for hackers to exploit software flaws.

Comment: OK. So where can I get up to date information on how a process's VA space looks like on modern Linux/Unices?

Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: NB `main` probably *isn't* the first thing in the text segment.