# Checking if a C/C++ pointer points to read-only memory during runtime (in Linux OS)

Tags: c++, c, linux

Back in the day, low-level C/C++ code identified whether a pointer `ptr` pointed to the read-only memory **in Linux OS** by doing:

```
extern char etext, edata;
...
(ptr > &etext) && (ptr < &edata);
```

And in fact, from time to time I still see that in action.

However, in the answers to a question posted by someone else last year ([Why does subtracting the value of etext from edata not give me the correct size for my text segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73779986/why-does-subtracting-the-value-of-etext-from-edata-not-give-me-the-correct-size)), it is shown that nowadays the traditional contiguous memory layout `text -> data -> bss -> heap -> ... -> stack -> kernel` is not guaranteed any longer.

This is rather puzzling to me, because as I said I see the above code in use still today. But also because the OP from that linked question understandably left a comment to the answers asking where could they find information about the memory section layouts nowadays - but answer authors did not know. This is quite a relevant technical information, but I also could not find further information about it that would help me assert whether the above code is still useful or how to modify it according to modern memory section layout rules.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206941/9890218) to a slightly different question suggests the following to check whether a pointer is in Static variable memory - to address the fact that nowadays the order of memory sections may be random:

```
(void*)(x) <= (void*)&end || (void*)(x) <= (void*)&edata
```

The rationale is that it suffices to check that the pointer is located before the end of BSS and Read-only data to affirm the pointer in Static memory.

So, my main question has two parts:

- to my understating, the latter approach above is silently assuming that, as random as the location of the heap might be, it comes after BBS **and** Read-only data - never in-between. Is that a safe assumption?
- if so, and knowing that text code segment at least comes first, can we adapt the approaches above to make sure to be detecting that a pointer is specifically in the read-only memory data (excluding BSS), in **modern Linux OSes**? I know there is no standard generalizable solution, but for now I am trying to solve the problem for Linux systems only (although solutions to Mac OSes may be quite similar, due to compilers often presenting equivalents to edata, etext and end for those OSes too).

My attempt is:

```
#include <iostream>
extern char etext, edata;


// the following is supposed to detect whether a pointer is in the Stack
// according to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206343/is-it-possible-to-identify-whether-an-address-reference-belongs-to-static-heap-s
void *stack_bottom;
bool __attribute__((noinline)) inStack(void *x) {
    void *stack_top = &stack_top;
    return x <= stack_bottom && x >= stack_top;
}

// then my attempt at checking if a pointer is in read-only data,
// excluding the BSS segment:
bool roMem(void* c) {
    if(&etext < &edata && &end > &edata)
    {
        return (c > &etext) && (c < &edata) && (!inStack((void*)c));
    } else if(&etext > &edata && &end > &edata)
    {
        return (void*)(c) <= (void*)&edata && !inStack((void*)c);
    } else if(&end < &edata)
    {
        return (void*)(c) > (void*)&end && (void*)(c) <= (void*)&edata && !inStack((void*)c);
    }
}

class Test {
    public:
    const char* d;
    Test(const char* c) { d = c; }
};

static const char* str5 = "short";

int main() {
    const char* str1 = "short";
    char* str2 = const_cast<char*>("short");
    const char str3[6] = {'s', 'h', 'o', 'r', 't', 0};
    const char* str4 = "longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";
    std::cout << roMem((void*)str1) << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << roMem((void*)(const char*)str2) << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << roMem((void*)str3) << std::endl; // prints 0
    std::cout << roMem((void*)str4) << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << roMem((void*)str5) << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << roMem((void*)"short") << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << roMem((void*)(const char*)2) << std::endl; // prints 0
    Test x((const char*)3);
    std::cout << roMem((void*)x.d) << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

In my Ubuntu 22.04 machine the above **seems** to be working (compiled with either g++12 and linker ld or clang++13), but the problem is that upon inspection ([following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784052/9890218)), it also seems to be generating the traditional sequence of data segment immediately after code text segment - in which case the old school `(ptr > &etext) && (ptr < &edata);` would suffice. The problem is when machines do not follow the traditional sequence of data segment immediately after text segment.

Comment: Pages can be protected arbitrarily by calling `mprotect`. Any library you have incorporated into your program might be mapping pages for its own purposes, with whatever protections it chooses. And I am not sure what current practice in Linux is, but pages above and below the currently active stack region may be marked no-read, no-write, to guard against inadvertent accesses out of bounds. So you cannot expect to test memory protection by comparing addresses. You need some system call that reports it or to test by trying an access and catching a trap.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oops, my bad. Yes, I will edit.

Comment: Are you talking about pointers to const data (like to character literals), or to locations inside Read Only Memory devices (like Flash or ROM)?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews good point - I am talking about pointers to const data is enough for my purposes. I do not need the extra granularity.

Comment: Read `/proc/self/maps`?

Comment: Stop assuming there's only **one** `.text` segment.  Every single shared object you load will have its own.

Comment: This question feels analogous to "what's the best way to drive while drunk?", in that there's doubtless a valid answer, but if you feel the need to ask the question, there's probably a bigger issue to be concerned about.  What are you trying to accomplish with this knowledge?

Comment: ^^^ exactly.  If you document a requirement for a pointer to a modifiable object, then it is reasonable to assume that you will get one.  If you instead get a pointer to an unmodifiable object (or to no object), then your attempt to write through it will most likely elicit a segfault -- and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger where did I ever say anything different from what you just said? Where did I say I want to modify the data stored in read-only?

Comment: I didn't say you did.  But that still begs @JeremyFriesner's question: what *do* you want it for?  If you're not going to try to write through the pointer, then why does it matter whether an attempt to do so could succeed?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know it is old-fashioned, but I asked a specific, detailed and non-trivial question because I want to learn something I am struggling with and for which little documentation exists. Isn't this what SO was supposed to be for back in the day, instead of for askers to have to justify the very reason why they have a question? I can't disagree more with the mentality of `But if you feel the need to ask the question, there's probably a bigger issue`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger cool — I suggest putting a mention of your motivations into the question so that people will understand why you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `/proc/self/maps`. Something along:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::optional<bool> roMem(uintptr_t addr) {
    auto f = std::ifstream("/proc/self/maps");
    while (f) {
        uintptr_t start;
        uintptr_t stop;
        char c;
        if ((f >> std::hex >> start >> c >> stop >> c >> c) && start <= addr && addr < stop) {
            return c != 'w';
        }
        f.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return {};
}

template <typename T> std::optional<bool> roMem(T* c) {
    return roMem(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(c));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ss, std::optional<bool> o) {
    return ss << (o ? *o ? "true" : "false" : "none");
}

static const char* str5 = "short";
int main() {
    std::cout << roMem(str5) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks, that is clever! Two issues: (1) a trivial one is that your `roMem` is inverting the `true` and `false` results; (2) it is detecting `std::cout << roMem((void*)(const char*)2) << std::endl` and `std::cout << roMem((void*)x.d) << std::endl` as if those were passed things located in the read-only memory section, when they are not

Comment: Good points. I believe the example code I posted is more than enough for readers to solve these problems. `std::optional<bool>` comes to mind, or throwing exceptions.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to solve the second problem, since I never read from `maps` and I still need to fully grasp your if-else condition, but I will give it a try first. Generally, though, my immediate suspicion is that your solution is not excluding things that are actually in the stack.

Comment: `how to solve the second problem` If the address is in maps, it's a valid address, otherwise it's not.

Comment: super! For my practical purposes, "false" and "none" seem equivalent - but great differentiation. The one detail is that the new version now gets `roMem((void*)str3)` wrong, doesn't it? `str3` is most definitively not in the ready-only mem section. I am still looking into why this is the one case off the track

Comment: @S08: "`str3` is most definitively not in read-only memory"  Says who?  You mean `const char str3[6] = {'s', 'h', 'o', 'r', 't', 0};` correct?  That is a read-only object (array of `const char`) and (being in `main`, where re-entrancy is forbidden, therefore only one instance can ever exist) it certainly is allowed to be placed into a read-only segment by the linker.

Comment: @BenVoigt that is interesting. I thought it would go to the stack section, not data read-only data section. At any rate, there is some interesting differentiation at play, since both the original answer (before the great edits) and `(ptr > &etext) && (ptr < &edata);` (in my system that sill follows old school contiguous sections) give `str3` out of data section.

Comment: @S08: I mean, there's nothing wrong with a toolchain that chooses to place it on the stack.  But because `main()` is special, it doesn't have to.  If you move your test code to an ordinary function called from `main()` does anything change?

Comment: @BenVoigt not really. Creating `void foo(){ const char str6[6] = {'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 0}; std::cout << roMem((void*)str6) << std::endl; }` and calling it from `main` still prints `true` with code above, as if `str6` were in the read-only data, instead of in the stack.

Comment: Then I'm suspecting that there's something wrong with the `(c != 'w')` test, possibly that the output on your system doesn't follow the EXACT format that the preceding line assumes.

Comment: @BenVoigt it turns out that I think the mistake was simpler: the last condition checked within the if-else condition it should be `stop > addr`, not `stop < addr`. Because it is checking whether `addr` is within the memory block being inspected.

Comment: `it should be stop > addr, not stop < addr` haha, that's a good one.